# Query to Find Best bus interchange Route along with list of Stops

Tags: mysql

I have a table named route_detail which has route_ID,ROUTE_NO,STOP_ID,STOP_POSITION AS column. I have multiple route and this table stored the detail of each route.

```
routeNo StopID  StopPosition
-----------------------------
1       1256       1
1       1245       2
1       1255       3
1       1236       4
1       1654       5
1       1655       6
2       676        1
2       1236       2
2       678        3
2       679        4
3       765        1
3       766        2
3       768        3
3       1236       4
3       1278       5
3       1290       6
```

What I want is when the START AND DESTINATION STOP ID is different (that is not on the same route, My query should be able to retrieve The Source RouteNo, Interchange Stop_ID and the Destination Route No.

For example from above if Source Stop ID = 1256 and Users Wants to Travel to Destination StopID= 679, So the output should be

```
routeNo StopID  StopPosition
-----------------------------
1       1256       1
1       1245       2
1       1255       3
1       1236       4
2       1236       2
2       678        3
2       679        4
```

I am totally new to queries and joins and hence doesn't know how to make a query to retrieve this kind of result set.
I am using mysql 5.7 with workbench

Thanks for all your assist in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question is more or less clear and well asked. However it's better to show what you already tried in SQL. Also this is not clear for me: "_What I want is when the START AND DESTINATION STOP ID is different (that is not on the same route_...", What's _START_ here? You don't have a START column so it is confusing. What you want is possible to achieve I think, but the final query will be very long and complex, you should thus provide us with a [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) of your table and data so we can play with it -> We need `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERTs` statements

Comment: Define 'best' - although I would note that an RDBMS is not optimised for these sorts of problems.

Comment: Sorry for using ambigious word like best. What i am looking for is a way to identify all the possible combination of routeNo for source and destination with an interchange. So I can have say 2 result. one is combination of routeNo1 and RouteNo3 with a total of 10 Stop in between, and another result with routeNo1 and RouteNo2 with a combination of 8 bus stop in between.

Comment: Thanks Thomas for the suggestion on sqlfiddle, here is the link to the fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8980e1. To better explain my query, Start and Destinatoin are the STOP_ID from where a person may board the bus. So for example, a person may board the bus from STOP_ID 2 and his destination is STOP_ID is 1578. So my flow was something like this 1) find all route_no where STOP_ID=1, 2) find all route_no where STOP_ID=1578, Then in case if both the Start and destination Stop_ID doesnt belong to the same Route_No, identify the common stop_ID between 2 routeNo via which we can route.